# Changing alpha value with increment of x coordinate value

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to give different alpha values to the same view at the same time?
I want to display color in a uiview, but it should faded out to a direction. Means I want to change its alpha value within increasing its x coordinate value.

Comment: try doing a gradient, alpha can only be set to a single value for a view at a given point of time

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this, but you have to remember that the range alpha value is from 0-1. So in this case you can define you can define change according to the width ie

```
float changeInAlphaPerX = 1/self.frame.width;
```

And where you are getting changed x value, you can do..

```
view.alpha = changeInAlphaPerX * x;
```

Hope it helps..